# iOS - Push notification not working in resigned IPA

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ipa

I am facing One problem with **APNS**. when I made One **IPA** file with my apple developer account push notification is working properly. But when I am giving that IPA to my client they are again resigning the app with their developer account. In this case push notification is not working. We have changed **cert.pem and key.pem** also as per their account. If I am making IPA using their credential push notification working properly but not working on resigned IPA. Please someone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Have u created distribution push certificate or using the same

Comment: You need to create distribution&development certificates for APNS.

Comment: Did you get a token ?

Comment: @UmaMadhavi client created distribution push certificate from their account  and that we are using.

Comment: @Maybe1 we have created for both developer account.

Comment: @CZ54 Yea I am getting.

Comment: So the pb is the certificate used to send the notif

Comment: My problem is APNS is working fine when making IPA with any of the 1 developer account. But notification is not working when ipa is resigned from 1 developer account to other account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I got my solution. Problem was from my server side. In development time while running app from xcode ,notification should be sent from sandbox server so set sandbox as true. After making IPA notification should come from production server so set production to true on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and tried two things I started getting notification on installing ipa in real device.

1. Make sure you have updated APNs Authentication Key to firebase console.
   Steps to do it.

- Go to firebase console and from Project overview --> Project settings --> Cloud messaging(tab)
- In apple app configuration, there is a option to upload APNs Authentication key.You can refer the below screenshot.

[image]

2. Generate adhoc ipa rather than development build. For that you need to have adhoc profile in the respective apple developer account. You can choose any existing adhoc profile or create new. And by selecting that adhoc profile in xCode, you can make archive ipa.

After following these two steps, you will get notification in installed ipa.